# MySQL: group by and IF statement

Tags: sql, mysql, group-by

By default, `parent_id` = 0. I want to select all records with `parent_id` = 0 and only the last ones with `parent_id` > 0.

I tried this, but it didn't work:

```
SELECT * FROM `articles`
  IF `parent_id` > 0 THEN
GROUP BY `parent_id`
HAVING COUNT(`parent_id`) >= 1
END;
ORDER BY `time` DESC
```

I mean, that if there are a few records with parent_id = 2, only one of them should be return. Also, if there a number of records with parent_id = 5, only one of them is returned. In other words, there should no more than one record of each parent_id apart from those having parent_id = 0.

What could be the solution?

Comment: What do you mean by "the last ones"? Do you mean the last few entered into the database?

Comment: You have to define "last" when you say "only the last ones with parent_id > 0".  Then someone can answer.

Comment: What do you mean by 'last ones'? Articles which have no other article referring to it as a parent?

Comment: I mean, that if there are a few records with parent_id = 2, only one of them should be returned. Also, if there a number of records with parent_id = 5, only one of them is returned. In other words, there should no more than one record of each parent_id apart from those having parent_id = 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you question well, you need all records with parent_id == 0 and only records with the greatest value of 'time' column for other parent_id's ? I suppose that `parent_id` + `time` is unique.

```
 SELECT a.* FROM `articles` a 
 INNER JOIN 
 (SELECT parent_id, MAX(`time`) AS `time` FROM `articles` WHERE parent_id >0) t
 ON (t.parent_id = a.parent_id AND a.`time` = t.`time`)

 UNION
 SELECT * FROM `articles` WHERE parent_id = 0;
```

Comment: +1 - I think this is a better version of what I was trying to describe.  Could probably use UNION ALL rather than UNION though considering the WHERE clause would not allow for duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

You're mashing all the concepts together.  `WHERE`, `GROUP BY`, and `HAVING` do different things.  You probably need to read this page more thoroughly:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html

But if I make some assumptions about what you're doing...

You probably want to start with this part:

`SELECT * FROM articles WHERE parent_id > 0`

But now you want to group together the articles that have the same parent.  Assuming that each article has an `id`, perhaps you want

`SELECT parent_id, COUNT(*) AS article_count FROM articles WHERE parent_id >= 0 GROUP BY parent_id`

Now, all of these rows will be parent_id values with at least one child article, but if you wanted to only look at parents with more than 2 child articles, you might then want:

```
SELECT parent_id, COUNT(*) AS article_count
FROM articles
WHERE parent_id >= 0
GROUP BY parent_id
HAVING article_count >= 2
```

That will show you the identity of all parent articles with at least 2 child articles.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to do it as two queries and join the results with a `UNION`.  I don't really have enough info from your post to know for sure what it would look like, but maybe something like this:

```
SELECT parent_id, time FROM articles WHERE parent_id = 0
UNION ALL
SELECT parent_id, MAX(TIME) FROM articles WHERE parent_id > 0
GROUP BY parent_id
```